# Protractor timeout on Jenkins with PhantomJS

Tags: angularjs, jenkins, protractor

I created a Jenkins job to run Protractor tests at midnight.
For headless testing, I'm using PhantomJS browser because I can't install Xvfb (don't have the rights).

I'm running the Protractor tests through a Grunt task.
On my local machine (windows), the grunt job works fine, and the tests pass.

On the server, I'm getting

> Failed: waiting for page to load for 10000ms
>
> ...
>
> Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "window.angular is undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"

My protractor-headless.conf:

```
exports.config = {
  directConnect: false,
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'phantomjs',
    'phantomjs.binary.path': require('phantomjs').path,
    'phantomjs.cli.args': []
  },
  seleniumServerJar: require('selenium-server-standalone-jar').path,

  framework: 'jasmine2',
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/**.spec.js'
  ],
  allScriptsTimeout: 30000,
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 200000,
    isVerbose: true//,
    //includeStackTrace : false
  },
  onPrepare: function() {
    'use strict';
    var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
      consolidateAll: true,
      savePath: 'test-results',
      filePrefix: 'xmloutput'
    }));
  }
};
```

And the Grunt Job:

```
protractor: {
  options: {
    configFile: 'src/test/javascript/protractor.conf.js',
    keepAlive: true,
    noColor: false,
    verbose: true,
    args: {
      // Arguments passed to the command
    }
  },
  headless: {
    options: {
      keepAlive: false,
      configFile: 'src/test/javascript/protractor-headless.conf.js'
    }
  }
}

...

grunt.registerTask('e2e-test-headless', [
  'protractor:headless'
]);
```

The test have access to the testing environment.
Any idea what can be the problem?